# Is there a way to programmatically determine which native DLLs are loaded in a .NET process?

Tags: .net, dll, native, dllimport

I know about `GetAssemblies()`, but that only gets the loaded managed assemblies.

In my specific case, I'm using SQL Server Compact, and I want to know the exact native DLL that gets loaded by the System.Data.SqlServerCe assembly (by `DLLImport`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the list of DLLs in the lower pane in Process Explorer.

If you want to do it in code, check `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify that I need it from within my process. Question updated. (BTW, I can't find that in PE either)